# Handling browser file download with ajax and spring controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, browser, download

In a project I need to pass few parameters from ajax POST to a spring controller which passes the parameters back to a java service which generates a file at a given location on server and returns back the file path to the controller. The post controller redirects the path to a GET controller further. Now the GET controller should allow a browser download of the file.

Everything works fine for me except the last step where in the GET spring controller generates a response in the browser as expected but no browser download window pops up for file download. Please please someone help me. I already struggles for 72 hours.

The 1st step (ajax request) works fine:

```
 function exportData(criteria) {

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'export/PDF',
        data: criteria,
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/pdf'}

});
    }
```

The 2nd step (POST controller) works fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "export/PDF", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public final String getDataToExportPDF(Model model, @RequestBody String    toJsonCriteria,
        final RedirectAttributes ra) throws Exception {

    try {

        AuditInput ai = auditService.formatDataToExport(toJsonCriteria);
        List<AuditData> ad = auditService.dataToExport(ai);
        logger.info("inside pdf export Post method ");
        String path = auditPdfService.createPDFFile(ai, ad);
        logger.info("inside export Post method");
        logger.info("inside pdf export Post method path: " + path);
        ra.addFlashAttribute("path", path);
        return "redirect:/download.html"; 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("inside export/PDF POST catch");           
        throw new IndiciumException("error creating audit PDF file");
    }

}
```

The 3rd step (GET controller which generates a response output but doesn't prompt to download):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadFile(
        @ModelAttribute("path") final String path, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {           
        logger.error("inside download get try");    

        File downloadFile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        out.write(bytes);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + downloadFile.getName()); 
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
        response.flushBuffer();

        out.close();
        out.flush();
        logger.info("the path is: " + path);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("inside download get catch");          
        throw new IndiciumException("Can't download the audit file");
    }


}
```

Comment: does method 'downloadFile()' gives any error?

Comment: nope it is successful. In firebug I can see the desired response but no prompt to download file. However I tried adding 'produces = "application/pdf"' to the @RequestMapping but it throws error "not Acceptable 406"

Comment: you mean the file downloads without the prompt?

Comment: no.. The file does not download at all but the response is written to the browser as I can see that in the console.

Comment: as far i can tell, ajax cannot be used to download the file..use submit instead

Comment: @Akash you are right, that is the reason I am redirecting it to another GET controller. but I think there is some other reason that it is not working. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: so whats the content of `download.html`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace below lines

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + downloadFile.getName()); 
response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
```

with:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadFile.getName() + "\"");
response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
```

I replaced "setHeader"s with "addHeader"s and added additonal double quotes to the filename and worked for me.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it still behaves the same way after making the changes specified by you. Please help :(

Comment: Please try to make a request directly to the downloadFile method instead of ajax request then it must work.

Comment: how can I avoid AJAX in this case when we are expecting an input value from the frontend before generating the file. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Try to call the getDataToExportPDF method inside downloadFile method.